# jquery datatable plug-in gets the searched results

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am developing an application, I used the jquery datatable plugin in this app from https://datatables.net/

Question : when any keyword is searched I need to get the result of search to do some operations on them how should I do that in javascript?

[image]

Let's say I need to do some operation on the records which are returned after "name" is searched

how should I implement it in the javascript?

Comment: What datasource are you using?

Comment: @markpsmith it is json type I fetched it from local storage in db with help of db.js library

Comment: what kind of operation do you need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
var data = $('#idOfTable').dataTable()._('tr', {"filter": "applied"});
```